# How well does an internal filter keep water oxygenated?

Tags: aquarium, filters

I'd like to use [Tom's Internal Filter](http://smile.amazon.com/dp/B00176GKM8/) which is an internal multistage filter, but I'm not sure if I'll get any oxygenation.

Background: I now have a three gallon tank and I'm trying to figure out what to do with it. Plants, shrimp, a snail and maybe a betta. I'll be cycling the tank with just gravel and plants for a month before I add anything other than a couple red cherry shrimp. I'm trying to avoid having too many stuff/wires in/around the tank. Will already need the wires for the filter, thermometer, heater, and lights, I don't want to add bubbler to the list if I can help it.

Comment: Bettas should have at least a 30 l aquarium.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oxygen is introduced into the aquarium through surface agitation.

Filters which feed water back into the aquarium through some kind of waterfall like the one you linked to will agitate the water, though not as much as a decent pump and airstone (think of all those little bubbles making their way to the top of the water to pop).

Without using a dissolved oxygen meter it is pretty much impossible to know how much oxygen you have in the water but what we do know is that there is less dissolved oxygen in water at higher temperatures, so the higher the temperature the more you need air pumps.

The filter you linked to may provide enough surface agitation, especially for lower temperatures, but it is difficult to say for sure. When there is not enough oxygen you will observe fish going to the surface for air.